# what is the difference with function parameters (params object[])

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand complex library (LinqToCodeDom), there are a lots of lambdas and delegates and so on. Two same code (on my opinion) works differently.
In both cases I try to pass an array of TypeA objects.

Works:

```
Func(new TypeA[] { new TypeA("value") });
```

Does not work:

```
TypeA [] v = new TypeA[] { new TypeA("value") }; 
Func(v);
```

Func accepts params object[]

When it does not work, it crashes with Null reference somewhere in depth of the lib.

**Update** complete line. Maybe it is more complex than just a Func call:

```
CodeMemberMethod cm = cls.AddMethod(
    MemberAttributes.Public, 
    m.ReturnType, 
    paramsAndName,
    Emit.@stmt(() =>
        CodeDom.Call(CodeDom.VarRef("obj"), m.Name)( *** PLACE FOR PARAM HERE*** )
);
```

Comment: Can you please create a short, but complete, program that demonstrates the problem? The reason I'm asking is that there should be no difference in the way the compiler treats these two statements, with the knowledge you've presented here, so there has to be something else making a difference here. On second thought, I have tested this in LINQPad, which may very well use .NET 4.5, so this might be something related to version, I'll test it on older versions as well.

Comment: Its seem yeah, i was mistaken, i guess the full code is needed to know why its different in your case

Comment: Can you put more code? like what is the variable m, i am trying to reproduce the issue

Comment: Is there an overload of `Func(...)`? Having overloads that accept `params` arguments can cause this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

after running and debugging i come to this - no i still don't know what the issue is exactly but - its related to expressions, this call generates two different types of expressions when executed

when you use

```
    Func(new TypeA[] { new TypeA("value") });
```

it generates

```
    {() => Invoke(Call(VarRef("obj"), value(Demo.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1).m.Name),new [] {new TypeA("value")})}
```

and when you use

```
    TypeA [] v = new TypeA[] { new TypeA("value") }; 
    Func(v);
```

it generates

```
   {() => Invoke(Call(VarRef("obj"), value(Demo.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1).m.Name),value(Demo.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1).v)}
```

notice the difference

```
   new [] {new TypeA("value")}
```

vs

```
   value(Demo.Program+<>c__DisplayClass1).v
```

where Demo is the name of namespace, Program is the class and v as you notice is the variable

**Edit 2.2**

to explain more i made this sample app

```
using System;

using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace TestXml
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public MyClass(string value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass[] parameter = new MyClass[] { new MyClass("1") };
            execute(() => TestInput( new MyClass[] { new MyClass("1") }));
            execute(() => TestInput(parameter));
        }

        public static void TestInput(params object[] parameters)
        {
            if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0) Console.WriteLine(parameters.GetType().FullName);
        }

        public static void execute(Expression<Action> exp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp);
        }

        public delegate void ParamsDelegate(params object[] param);
    }
}
```

**The Output**

```
() => TestInput(new [] {new MyClass("1")})
() => TestInput(value(TestXml.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).parameter)
```

**Edit 3**

To know the reason of the difference in behavior i asked [the question on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9bfc5e8f-7af5-4314-b27e-4fcbf4eaf6af/expressions-params-and-arrays-as-parameters) and got this answer:

> "execute(() => TestInput( new MyClass[] { new MyClass("1") }));"
>
> doesn't capture anything, the lambda expression doesn't use any
>   variables.
>
> "captures a pointer to the parameter variable?"
>
> I supposed you could say that. It's not really a pointer, the variable
>   parameter gets stored in a object field instead of being stored in the
>   stack, that c__DisplayClass0 you see is a class generated by the
>   compiler to hold the parameter variable

which leads to say that this mostly a bug with how LinqToCodeDom evaluates expressions, it seem they are not handling this case.

Comment: OK. I'm not getting this either. Can you explain better/again?

Comment: I tested it in LINQPad (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz8kbxx67z0ztwp/SO17504773.linq), and it passes in the array as the parameter in both cases, doesn't treat it different at all. In other words, the contents of the array inside `Func` is always just 1 object of type `TypeA`, not an array of that.

Comment: Meywd
    Func(new TypeA[] { new TypeA("value"),new TypeA("value2") }); also works. I think in both cases it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Both method calls are functionally the same.

In the first case the C# compiler will generate a variable to hold the array which is equivalent to the second case.

Consider the following C# code (in LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    CallFunc(new [] { new Foo() });

    var foos = new [] { new Foo() };
    CallFunc(foos);
}

public class Foo { }

void CallFunc(Foo[] foos) { }
```

IL that is generated:

```
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     // These first two lines load 1
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1    // for the size of the array
IL_0003:  newarr      Foo // Create the array of type Foo with the size
IL_0008:  stloc.1     // Pops the array into a variable
IL_0009:  ldloc.1     // These next two lines load
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.0    // the first index (0) of the array
IL_000B:  newobj      Foo..ctor // Creates a new Foo
IL_0010:  stelem.ref  // Loads Foo into the array
IL_0011:  ldloc.1     // Loads the array onto the stack
IL_0012:  call        CallFunc // Calls the function
IL_0017:  nop         // Same thing repeats below with some extra variable loading
IL_0018:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0019:  newarr      Foo
IL_001E:  stloc.1     
IL_001F:  ldloc.1     
IL_0020:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0021:  newobj      Foo..ctor
IL_0026:  stelem.ref  
IL_0027:  ldloc.1     
IL_0028:  stloc.0     // Pops the array into foos
IL_0029:  ldarg.0     
IL_002A:  ldloc.0     // Loads the array from foos
IL_002B:  call        CallFunc

CallFunc:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ret         

Foo..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0006:  ret
```

The difference between the code is two instructions for loading and reading `foos`.

The equivalent C# code for this IL:

```
var arrayLength = 0;
var foos = new Foo[arrayLength];
var firstIndex = 0;
var foo = new Foo();
foos[firstIndex] = foo;
CallFunc(foos);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's no difference between your two code samples, as well as when you just call

```
Func(new TypeA("value")); //the compiler will create an array for you because of params
```

Comment: The difference between his code and your code is that the underlying array will in your case be `object[]` and in his case `TypeA[]`, which will only matter if he stores new objects into it.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean, I think you're right about this.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen its written as `new TypeA[]{new TypeA()}` and not `new []{new TypeA()}`. Isn't there a difference between the two??

Comment: Only in syntax, in this case, in the compiled code, no. `new[] { ... }` is short-hand for "figure out the best type for the array". In this case the type will be `TypeA[]`, so there is no difference.